# Convertir String en array JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, string

Tengo el siguiente string:

```
var str = 
  "### Titulo 1
     #### Subtitulo 1
     #### Subtitulo 2
     #### Subtitulo 3
   ### Titulo 2
     #### Subtitulo 1
     #### Subtitulo 2"
```

Habría alguna forma de a partir de este String generar un array con este contenido:

```
var arr = [
  "### Titulo 1
     #### Subtitulo 1
     #### Subtitulo 2
     #### Subtitulo 3",
  "### Titulo 2
     #### Subtitulo 1
     #### Subtitulo 2"
]
```

Comment: Has probado [`split()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) ?

Comment: Si, pero pasandole un argumento de "###" genera un array con 7 elementos, ya que los subtitulos tambien tienen "#"...

Comment: ¿Tu cadena incluye los saltos de linea y el tabulado (ya sea con `tabs` o espacios) anterior que se muestra en la pregunta? ¿Podrías incluir el intento fallido en tu pregunta?

Comment: Si, los incluye

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Una de las formas que se me ocurren para realizar la tarea es construir tu propio analizador.

Se puede separar la cadena usando como separador el carácter de Línea Nueva (`\n`) en conjunto con el carácter de numeral o almohadilla (`#`), pero eso quitaría o eliminaría el primer carácter `#` de la linea siguiente que queremos separar.

Para solventarlo usaremos el método [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) del tipo `Array`, para añadir un carácter `#` a la línea que lo perderá por hacer el uso de [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split).

Por ejemplo:

```js
const cadena =
`### Titulo 1
  ### Subtitulo 1
  ### Subtitulo 2
  ### Subtitulo 3
### Titulo 2
  ### Subtitulo 1
  ### Subtitulo 2
  ### Subtitulo 3
### Titulo 3
  ### Subtitulo 1
  ### Subtitulo 2
  ### Subtitulo 3`;

let array = cadena.split(`\n#`).map((item, index) => {
  if(!index) { // si el índice es 0, se retorna el elemento sin alterar
    return item;
  }
  return `#${item}`
});
array.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Esta solución aplica para cualquier cadena que tenga la estructura aportada en la pregunta.

Comment: Si va perfecto, ojo que al hacer el map también se añade # en el primer elemento, pero con un condicional y cogiendo el index se soluciona.

Comment: Claro, eso no lo vi. Muy buena observación. Editaré la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Creo que buscas algo similar a esto separo por el elemento ### Titulo elimino el primer elemento y luego le concatelo el parametro de búsqueda ### Titulo

```
var str =`### Titulo 1
     #### Subtitulo 1
     #### Subtitulo 2
     #### Subtitulo 3
   ### Titulo 2
     #### Subtitulo 1
     #### Subtitulo 2`;
var separador=str.split("### ");
separador.shift()
console.log('### '+separador[0]);
console.log('### '+separador[1]);
```

Comment: Si, es la solución que pense pero los titulos no son siempre los mismos...

Comment: Otra opción es splitear por "###  " (con espacio en el string) como el subtitulo tiene 4 almohadillas no te las detectaria o utilizar una expresión regular y orra opción mas difícil pero mas segura seria serializarlos

Comment: He probado a hacer el split con "###" pero si detecta el subtítulo, creo que mi solución podría ser una expresión regular, pero no sabría como aplicarla

Comment: Prueba con el cambio de filtro seguro que te funciona

Comment: @RicardoAlvarado si haces una Expresion regular con `\b` puedes acotar la busqueda